# How to make R program (with Shiny) more modular

Tags: r, shiny, coding-efficiency

*Entire R code on [GitHub](https://github.com/ArtieLadie/RanglaPunjab/blob/master/R/RanglaPunjab.R)*

I have R code that allows person to paint palette, i.e.

```
PaintPalette("GoldenTemple","GoldenTemple2")
```

Calls public-facing `PaintPalette` which then calls internal-facing `RenderPalette` to plot this

[image]

However, I have shiny-based function that allows user to CherryPick their own palette

```
CherryPickPalette("GoldenTemple","GoldenTemple2")
```

will launch Shiny ....

[image]

but the code to Render the Palette is duplicated within the shiny code ...... how to streamline this?

```
CustomPal <- function(new_pal){

    #snip
    cherrypickedpalette <- runApp(list(
      ui = fluidPage(
        #snip
      ),
      server = function(input,output,session){
        outputdata <-  reactive({
          input$col
        })


        #snip

        output$cherrycolors=renderPlot({
          if (!is.null(input$col))
          {
            n <- length(input$col)
            old <- graphics::par(mar = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
            on.exit(graphics::par(old))
            graphics::image(1:n, 1, as.matrix(1:n), col = input$col,
                          ylab = "", xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n", bty = "n")
            graphics::rect(0, 0.9, n + 1, 1.1, col = grDevices::rgb(1, 1, 1, 0.8), border = NA)
            graphics::text((n + 1) / 2, 1, labels = "Cherry-Picked Palette", cex = 2, family = "serif")}
        }, height = 450, width = 450 ) 


       #snip
      }#end server
    )#end list
    )#end runApp
  }#end if interactive
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you should just be able to call the `RenderPalette()` function inside your `renderPlot()` to eliminate the duplication

```
 output$cherrycolors=renderPlot({
        if (!is.null(input$col)) {
            RenderPalette(input$col, "Cherry-Picked Palette")
        }}, height = 450, width = 450 )
```